# Parted: how to solve Location outside of device error?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zfs, parted

I was trying to create new partition from existing unallocated space on /dev/sda,  but whenever I set the 'start and end', I get `location outside of device error`. Below is the full output:

root@server01:/# parted /dev/sda
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print free
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2199GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

```
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 2      17.4kB  1049kB  1031kB                     bios_grub
 1      1049kB  25.8GB  25.8GB  zfs
        25.8GB  25.8GB  3584B   Free Space
 3      25.8GB  36.5GB  10.7GB  zfs
 4      36.5GB  47.2GB  10.7GB  zfs
 5      47.2GB  1100GB  1052GB  zfs
 9      1100GB  1100GB  8392kB
        1100GB  2199GB  1100GB  Free Space

(parted) mkpart                                                           
Partition name?  []? 10                                                   
File system type?  [ext2]? zfs                                            
Start? 1100GiB                                                            
End? 2199GiB                                                              
Error: The location 2199GiB is outside of the device /dev/sda.
(parted) mkpart                                                      
Partition name?  []?                                                      
File system type?  [ext2]? zfs                                            
Start? 1100GiB                                                            
End? 2198GiB                                                             
Error: The location 2198GiB is outside of the device /dev/sda.
```

If I set the `End?` as 100%, I'm able to create new partition. This leads to question on how to create multiple partitions if there is requirement to create 3 partitions with 100G, 500G and 500G.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your disk has an end point of 2199GB. You are using GiB to set the size. GiB are larger than GB so 2199GiB is bigger than 2199GB and therefore beyond the end of the partition.

Use GB instead of GiB to set the size.

Comment: Also it should be mentioned that zfs prefers disks be unpartitioned as it's not only a filesystem but also a volume manager.